# Accessing the original file name of R markdown parameters file

Tags: r, parameters, markdown

I want to provide the user a convenient way to define the input file. For this I am using the parameters functionality in markdown. If I "knit with parameters" I get asked for the input file.

Is there any chance to retrieve the file name? Because I am creating during the markdown some different files and I would use the filename of the input file as a prefix. So far, the file gets uploaded in a temp directory and there, the original file name is lost.

How can I get the file name and location via drop down menu into my markdown document? I don't want the user to write the path and filename manually.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "11/16/2021"
output: html_document
params:
  date_file:
    label: "date file"
    value: 'dates.tsv'
    input: file
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

Filename: `r params$date_file`
````

Comment: It's hard to deduce exactly what happens when you hit "Knit with Parameters..." because RStudio runs `rmarkdown::render` in a new R session. That means you can't step into the function call with `debug` from your own session. If you don't find a satisfactory answer here, then it might be worth raising the issue on their [GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown), or wherever their GitHub says to raise issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As alternative to using the Shiny runtime, you can also use [Shiny Gadgets](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/gadgets.html) in combination with [customized Knit button behavior](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-knit.html) (To my understanding, this is largely what's happening when you [use 'Knit with Parameters'](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html#the-interactive-user-interface))

You'll need two things: a function to run the gadget, a function to run when knitting.

The gadget is essentially a Shiny app, but you can use specialized UI elements from `miniUI`. As a mini-app, there's a lot more you can do, but here's a basic implementation.

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)

get_file_param <- function(){
  
  ui <- miniPage(
    miniContentPanel(
      
      fileInput("dateFile", "Date File")
      
      # ...Other UI elements to collect other parameters... 
      
    ),
    miniTitleBar(
      NULL,
      right = miniButtonBlock(
        miniTitleBarCancelButton(),
        miniTitleBarButton("done", "Done", primary = TRUE))
    )
    
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    # Handle the Done button being pressed
    observeEvent(input$done, {
      # Return the full file info data.frame. See ?shiny::fileInput
      stopApp(input$dateFile)
    })
    
  }
  
  runGadget(
    app = ui, 
    server = server, 
    viewer = paneViewer() #dialogViewer("Knit with Parameters - Custom UI")
  )
  
}
```

The knit function will call the gadget and then use its output in a call to `rmarkdown::render`

```
knit_with_file <- function(input, ...){
  
  fileInfo <- get_file_param()
  
  rmarkdown::render(
    input,
    params = list(
      date_file = list(name = fileInfo$name, datapath = fileInfo$datapath)
    ),
    envir = globalenv()
  )
  
}
```

To customize the knit button, you provide a function to the `knit` field in the document YAML header. The R Markdown cookbook suggest you keep this in a package, but I put both of the above functions in file ("knitFx.R"), which the rmarkdown document will source.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "11/16/2021"
output: html_document
params:
  date_file: 'dates.tsv'
knit: (function(input, ...) {

    source("knitFx.R")
    
    knit_with_file(input, ...)

  })
---
  
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

**Original Name of Uploaded File**: *`r params$date_file$name`*

**Local Temp File Path**: *`r params$date_file$datapath`*
````

When the user clicks "Knit", a UI will be displayed to choose the file. Based on implementation above, the `name` and `datapath` will then be available to use in the rmarkdown document.

Here's the rendered HTML document:
[image]

Comment: Nice. Note that the default value of parameter `date_file` is a string while the expected value is a list. That could cause problems if (for whatever reason) the default actually used. Could that field in the YAML header simply be deleted?

Comment: You can't delete the field from the YAML header because `rmarkdown::render` will match its `params` argument against it. You can instead supply a list as the default. Something along the lines of `date_file: !r list(name = 'dates.tsv', datapath = './dates.tsv')`

Answer (score 5):

You could have users select a file in the *rendered* document by [embedding a Shiny application](https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/content/2671/Combining-Shiny-R-Markdown.html). The caveat is that all expressions involving dependencies of the user's selection have to be wrapped inside of `reactive()`. That is obviously not optimal if you are trying to teach R, but in case it helps or inspires a better answer, here is an example:

```r
## Create a TSV file for testing
cat("x\ty\n1\t2\n3\t4\n", file = "test.tsv")
```

````markdown
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Users can select a file by interacting with an embedded Shiny application.

```{r ui, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  fileInput("file", label = "Select a TSV file:", accept = ".tsv")
)
```

User input is stored in a named list-like object `input`, 
but this object can only be accessed inside of a _reactive context_.

```{r test1, error=TRUE}
input$file$name
## Name of file selected by user ... _not_ an absolute or relative path
fn <- reactive(input$file$name)
fn
## Absolute path of temporary copy of file
dp <- reactive(input$file$datapath)
dp
```

Don't be misled by how `fn` and `dp` are printed. They are not 
strings, but _reactive expressions_. As as a result, they, too, 
must be handled inside of a reactive context.

```{r test2}
class(fn)
reactive(class(fn()))
```

Some more examples:

```{r test3, error=TRUE}
## Define reactive data
dd <- reactive(read.table(file = dp(), sep = "\t", header = TRUE))
## Do stuff with it
reactive(names(dd()))
reactive(nrow(dd()))
## Write object to file in _working directory_
reactive(saveRDS(dd(), file = sub("tsv$", "rds", fn())))
```
````

Comment: Hi Mikael, interesting solution... Is there a way to get the absolut/relative path to the file, rather than just the file name... 
Not exactly what I am looking for, but gives me new options to use it on my script...

Comment: Unfortunately, `input$file$name` only preserves the part of the absolute path after the last path separator. If you are saving files to your working directory (which I claim is good practice, because users will not expect files to be created anywhere else on their system), then not having the absolute path is OK.

Comment: I have updated the `.Rmd` slightly. I was mistakenly passing `input$file$name` to `read.table` when I should have been passing `input$file$datapath`.